# div is not on the code

Tags: php, html

I'm generating html code with a string this way

```
foreach ($busquedas as $busqueda) {
        $checked = $busqueda->porDefecto ? "checked" : ' ';
        $radio_html = "<input type='radio' radio-id='".$busqueda->id."' name='default' class='radio-default' value='Por defecto' checked =".$checked." > Por defecto";
        $html .= "<div class='col-md-12 search-div'>";
            $html .= "<div class='col-md-12'>";
                $html .= "<div class='col-md-6'>".$busqueda->nom."</div>";
                $html .= "<div class='col-md-6'>".$_SESSION['user_rol'] == 0?$radio_html:''."</div>";//if $radio_html is shwon the paren div col-md-6 is not shown
            $html .="</div>";
            $html .= "<div class='col-md-12'>";
                $html .= "<div class='col-md-6'><button class='btn btn-default load_search_btn' search_id='".$busqueda->id."'>Cargar</button></div>";
                $html .= "<div class='col-md-6'><button class='btn btn-default delete_search_btn' search_id='".$busqueda->id."'>Eliminar</button></div>";
            $html .="</div>";
        $html .="</div>";
    }
```

When $radio_tml is shown the parent div with class col-md-6 is not on the code but if $radio_html is shown the div is shown too,I thought some tag is not  closed but I can't see it

Comment: `$html = "";` then the rest of your code.

Comment: check if the session array has value; use error reporting for that

Comment: Yes I know ,its outside the for,I didn't copied here

Comment: Just for clarity (and I've run into issues with this), add parens appropriately to: `$_SESSION['user_rol'] == 0?$radio_html:''` .. as in `(($_SESSION['user_rol'] == 0)?$radio_html:'')`

Comment: @rd_afs2 better you include that, because thats the only clue to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your code implies that when you have

```
$_SESSION['user_rol'] == 0
```

the div section after that is not closed

You should add brackets as IncredibleHat was saying or add the `</div>` in the if statement (and not only in the else)

Comment: This is why I told him to use proper parens.